# How to set a default value of radio_buttons in simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am going to set the default value for `radio_buttons` in `simple_form`. This is my code:

`<%= f.input :library_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: Library.library_types.collect { |k,_| [k.capitalize, k]} , checked: 'custom’%>`

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum library_type: [:standard, :custom]
  ...
end

2.2.3 :002 > Library.library_types.collect { |k,_| [k.capitalize, k]}
 => [["Standard", "standard"], ["Custom", "custom"]]
```

I added a option `checked: ‘custom’`. when creating a new library, the `custom` would be default selected.

However, this will cause an error that when a user already choose a `library_type`. When a user edit a library, it will select the `custom` as well, even if the user selected the `standard`.

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move this logic to the controller.
In `new` action you have to set the `library_type` field to `custom`, and it will do it for you.
Something like

```
class LibrariesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @library = Library.new(library_type: 'custom')
    render 'edit'
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

  def edit
    #find @library here
    render 'edit'
  end

  def update
    ...
  end
end
```

So, it will set up `library_type` to `custom` for new instances and will not overwrite it for already created records.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I want.